# How to find (many) documents with the same property in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, sense

I have an index with "event" documents. Each event has a property called "receiptId". Several events can have the same receiptId.

I need to find a receiptId with at least 1000 events - how can I write some kind of query for that? I use Sense.

I'm a beginner with Elasticsearch and I've tried to read their documentation, but can't seem to figure it out. I hope my question is clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) with the `min_doc_count` setting, like this:

```
POST events/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "receipts": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "receiptId",
            "min_doc_count": 1000
         }
      }
   }
}
```